# Make a report from 3 different tables using MAX and COUNT?

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

I have a database with patients, doctors, cabinets  and visits.

Patients (**id_pac**, FirstName, LastName)

Doctors (**id_med**, FirstName, LastName, Speciality)

Cabinets (**id_cab**, Name)

Vizits (id_viz, Date_viz, **Medic_id,Patient_id, Cabinet_id**)

One doctor can make visits on different patients, on different cabinets, on different dates.

I need to find out (with a subquery or with a join ? , but NOT with intermediary tables or views),  in one report :

1. one column with the doctor's **complete name** : CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName)  (*DISTINCT*),
2. one column with **the cabinet name in which the doctor was having the biggest number of visits**
   and
   3.one column with the number of visits for this cabinet.

I have tried to figure out how can i get this information, but all what I can have is
the list of doctors with every cabinets in which he was having visits, with the total number of visits / cabinet  :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(d.FirstName,' ',d.LastName) AS CompleteName
     , c.Name                             AS CabinetName  
     , dv.MaxVisits                       AS MaxVisits
FROM Doctors AS d
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT Medic_id
           , MAX(NumVisits) AS MaxVisits
      FROM
        ( SELECT Medic_id
               , Cabinet_id
               , COUNT(*) AS NumVisits
          FROM Vizits AS v
          GROUP BY Medic_id
                 , Cabinet_id
        ) AS grp
      GROUP BY Medic_id
    ) AS dv
    ON dv.Medic_id = d.id_med
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT Medic_id
           , Cabinet_id
           , COUNT(*) AS NumVisits
      FROM Vizits AS v
      GROUP BY Medic_id
             , Cabinet_id
    ) AS mcv
    ON  mcv.Medic_id = dv.Medic_id
    AND mcv.NumVisits = dv.MaxVisits
  LEFT JOIN Cabinets AS c
      ON c.id_cab = mcv.Cabinet_id
```

Comment: Uau, this is exactly what I need. I don't think that were any chances to find this query by myself. I also give you a 'click' for your potential space trip :)Thanks

Comment: @GabrielMandu: Thnx. You can also tick this answer, if it was helpful.

Comment: :I have post my variant for this subquery. Please let me know if you see some differences , because it's important to see if I forgot or escape something.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to better understand this subquery and I found an another way (a simple one i believe). The code is :

```
SELECT
CONCAT(me.Nume,' ',me.Prenume) AS Medic,
x.Denumire,
MAX(x.nrviz) AS maxviz
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            v.Medic_id,
            c.Denumire,
            COUNT(v.id_viz) AS nrviz
        FROM
            vizite v
        LEFT JOIN
            cabinete c
        ON(v.Cabinet_id=c.id_cab)
        GROUP BY
            v.Medic_id,
            v.Cabinet_id
        ORDER BY
            nrviz DESC) as x
LEFT JOIN
 medici me
ON (x.Medic_id=me.id_med)
LEFT JOIN
 cabinete ca
ON (x.Denumire=ca.Denumire)
GROUP BY
Medic
ORDER BY
    Medic,  
    maxviz DESC
```

@ypercube : Please let me know if you see some differences , because it's important to see if I forgot or escape something.